# How to build a stream while it is being uploaded in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asynchronous, stream

I am trying to take a file and split it into piece and then push each new smaller file piece to azure.  I have tried writing a MemoryStream to azure, but that causes the file to upload immediately, but the file is basically empty.  I have tried using a BufferedStream which allows the data to be sent as i am writing to it, but i am not sure how to end the stream.  I have tried to close each of the different streams i am using, but that does not work as it results in a stream closed exception.  Any idea how to mark the stream as complete so the azure library will know to finish the file upload?

It does work to wait until the full file is build and then upload the memory stream, but i would like to be able to write to it while it is uploading if possible.

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containerName");

using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path)
{
    int key = 0;
    CsvWriter csvWriter = null;
    MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
    BufferedStream bufferedStream = null;
    StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
    Task<StorageUri> uploadTask = null;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        await foreach (model row in csv.GetRecordsAsync<MyModel>())
        {
            if (row.KeyColumn != key)
            {
                if (memoryStream != null)
                {
                    //Wiat for the current upload to finish
                    await csvWriter.FlushAsync();
                    csvWriter.Dispose();
                    await uploadTask;
                }

                //Start New Upload
                key = row.KeyColumn;

                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(memoryStream)
                streamWriter = new StreamWriter(bufferedStream);
                csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                csvWriter.WriteHeader<MyModel>();
                await csvWriter.FlushAsync();

                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"file_{key}.csv");
                uploadTask = blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(bufferedStream);
            }

            csvWriter.WriteRecord(row);
            await csvWriter.FlushAsync();
        }

        if (memoryStream != null)
        {
            await csvWriter.FlushAsync();
            csvWriter.Dispose();
            await uploadTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you pass the file stream to the blockblob? Or are you creating new file contents? In the latter case, I would create a class that inherits `Stream` and create the contents on the fly when `Read` is called.

Comment: You split one file into pieces and upload pieces to Azure blob. Is that you will store one piece as a blob or just store the whole while as a blob?

Comment: I want to split the file by the first column.  every row with the same value in the first column i want to copy into a new CSV file with the same headers.

Comment: I am trying to write new content directly to a memory stream. but i am open to other ways of doing this.

Comment: According to my understanding, you will create some new csv files as the first column value and upload these csv files to Azure blob. If so, I think it is a better way that we  create these file at first. Then we upload file union we finish creating.

Comment: That is what i have done for now and the works, but i was wondering if it was possible to to upload without creating a file first.